# Nextjs 7.0.2 getInitialProps execute multiple times

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga, next.js, server-side-rendering

My project is using next-redux-wrapper(2.0.0) and next-redux-saga(3.0.0), I prefer calling API via redux-saga on server-side, but the API was called multiple times. I'll calling API to do some logging and handle some data , calling multiple times of API will make the data wrong.

Here is my codes, any solution?

```
// index.js
Index.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx: { isServer, store } }) => {
  if (isServer) store.dispatch(appOnServer())
}

// saga.js
import axios from 'axios'
import { take, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { actionToListen, actionToActivate } from './actions'
function * callApi {
  try {
      const data = call(axios.get, 'https://some_api_url')
      yield put(actionToActivate(data.data))
  }  catch (err) {  console.log(err) } 

}
function * rootSaga() {
   try {
      yield take(actionToListen())
   } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
}

export default rootSaga
```

Comment: getInitialProps is only run once per render. Sometimes HMR(hot module replacement) kicks in and reloads the page really fast while booting up. The correct way to test per-render is to do curl http://localhost:3000, since then there are no other factors.